# How to prevent Emacs from creating two windows on startup Windows 10?

Tags: start-up

**When I start Emacs not from the command line on Windows 10 it creates two windows, not one. Is there any way to make the blue window go away?** I usually need 4-5 instances of Emacs running so it clutters up my set up. And No, I, unfortunately, cannot use Linux.

[image: two windows]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using the `emacs` command, use the `runemacs` command (which is provided in the Emacs distribution, in the same `bin` directory as `emacs.exe`.

`emacs` is a command-line program that can run Emacs in the text window, or launch the Emacs GUI-- but if it does that, the command-line window remains.  `runemacs` knows about the windowing system, and only launches the Emacs GUI, so the vestigial command-line window is not created.

Comment: For those of us who do stuff like pin applications to our taskbar, if you pin emacs once it's running you will get a shortcut to emacs.exe, but if you right-click the icon, then right-click on emacs in the pop-up menu, then choose properties, you can change the target of the shortcut to runemacs.exe... now your pinned shortcut will not open the extra window.